# Excel index search using a wildcard character ("*")

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to use an INDEX search instead of a VLOOKUP because I want to display all associated cells with one String in a cell. For example, if my String is "Bob", I want to be able to search Column B for all instances of "Bob", and then produce all associated values from Column C. This would be displayed elsewhere vertically in different column.

Here's the formula from a [website](https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/10/25/how-to-return-multiple-values-using-vlookup-in-excel/) that I currently use to do this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$C$1188,SMALL(IF((D$2=$B$1:$B$1188),ROW($B$1:$B$1188)-MIN(ROW($B$1:$B$1188))+1,""),ROW(A1)),2),"")
```

But, my data isn't perfect and very large, so I want to be able to use the wildcard character '*', so I search 'Bo' & "*" and return all values in Column B that start with "Bo". The formula would then be modified to:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$C$1188,SMALL(IF((D$2 & "*"=$B$1:$B$1188),ROW($B$1:$B$1188)-MIN(ROW($B$1:$B$1188))+1,""),ROW(A1)),2),"")
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. I've tried this on a much smaller scale as well, and it still isn't functioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:$B$1188)/(LEFT($B$1:$B$1188,LEN($D$2))=$D$2),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I played around with this and it doesn't seem to be working. However, I did realize that the core issue is with the `D$2=$B$1:$B$1188` section. That returns an array like {TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, etc.}. But for some reason, if you do `D$2 & "*"=$B$1:$B$1188`, it returns all FALSE.